# How to terminate an ILaunch object effectively?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a wrapper over `JavaLaunchDelegate` and created a new `ZLaunchConfigurationDelegate` extending this . In this wrapper I tried to terminate the previous running `Launch` using `Launch.terminate` sometimes it fails to terminate .

Java Code :

```java
public static ILaunch getLaunchObject(String launchName) {
    ILaunch launchObj = null;
    ILaunchManager launchManager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();
    ILaunch[] launches = launchManager.getLaunches();
    for(int i=0 ; i<launches.length ; i++) {
        ILaunch launch = launches[i];
        ILaunchConfiguration config = launch.getLaunchConfiguration();
        if(config != null) {
            String configName = config.getName();
            if(configName.equals(serviceName)) {
                launchObj = launch;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return launchObj;
}

public static void terminateLaunch(String launchName){
    ILaunch launch = getLaunchObject(launchName);
    if(launch != null){
        launch.terminate();
    }
}

terminateLaunch("mylaunch");
```

I want to force kill the process if `launch.terminate` will not work .

**Goal**

If i got the process id from an eclipse launch object . I will kill the process using os command .

Is there any way to get the process id from an launch object?

Thank You ,

Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try killing all the processes and debug targets (if this Launch is in Debug mode) first and terminate the Launch.

```
private void terminate(ILaunch launch){
    try{
        IProcess [] processList = launch.getProcesses();
        for(IProcess process : processList) {
            if( ! process.isTerminated() ) {
                process.terminate();                    
            }               
            launch.removeProcess(process);
        }

        IDebugTarget [] debugTargetList = 
            launch.getDebugTargets();
        for(IDebugTarget debugTarget : debugTargetList) {
            launch.removeDebugTarget(debugTarget);
        } 

        launch.terminate();

    }catch(Exception ex) {
       // Exception
    }
 }
```